# Undefined symbol in Diab linker

Tags: c, linker-errors, scons, undefined-symbol, lzma

i'm trying to run LZMA (C version) (7-zip.org/sdk.html) on an MPC5748G from NXP, by compiling a simple code to encode/decode a stream , i get the follwing WARNING from the linker:

```
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
..\tools\wr\mpc5748_wr594\diab\5.9.4.2\WIN32\bin\dcc.exe -c -Xenum-is-best -Xrtti-off -Xexceptions-off -Xforce-declarations -ee1481 -tPPCVLEES:simple -Xsection-split -g3 -XO -Xsize-opt -DTGT_MPC5748_WR594 -DC_DERIVATIVE_MPC5748G -DFREESCALE_OS -DAUTOSAR_OS_USED -DOSDIABPPC -DADC_INTERRUPT_TYPE=MCAL_ISR_TYPE_NONE -DCAN_INTERRUPT_TYPE=MCAL_ISR_TYPE_NONE -DGPT_INTERRUPT_TYPE=MCAL_ISR_TYPE_NONE -DICU_INTERRUPT_TYPE=MCAL_ISR_TYPE_NONE -DLIN_INTERRUPT_TYPE=MCAL_ISR_TYPE_NONE -DPWM_INTERRUPT_TYPE=MCAL_ISR_TYPE_NONE -DSPI_INTERRUPT_TYPE=MCAL_ISR_TYPE_NONE -DTGT_DBG -DTGT_APP -DCFG_CFG -DCFG_CAN -DCFG_CSL -DCFG_MCU -DCFG_DUT -DCFG_MEM -DCFG_MOV -DCFG_GPI -DCFG_GPO -DCFG_ADC -DCFG_SED -DCFG_FRY -DCFG_LPM -DCFG_ETH -IC:\GW_MCU\tools\wr\mpc5748_wr594\diab\5.9.4.2\include -Ibsw\mcal\mcalAS\inc -I. lib\lzma\Alloc.c -o lib\lzma\Alloc.o
..\tools\wr\mpc5748_wr594\diab\5.9.4.2\WIN32\bin\dcc.exe -tPPCVLEES:simple -u__lear_calypso_memory_init -Wl,-Xremove-unused-sections -Wl,-Xunused-sections-list -lc -Wl,-m6 -Wm bsw/mcal/mcalm/linkerDescriptionVLE_App.dld -o out\app\BmwBdc2018GwmDutApp.elf out/app\objToLink.inl 1>out/app/BmwBdc2018GwmDutApp.map
dld: warning: Undefined symbol '__HEAP_END' in file 'sbrk.o(C:\GW_MCU\tools\wr\mpc5748_wr594\diab\5.9.4.2\PPCVLEE\libchar.a)'
dld: warning: Undefined symbol 'LzmaEncProps_Init' in file 'lib/lzma/LzmaLib.o'
dld: warning: Undefined symbol '__HEAP_START' in file 'sbrk.o(C:\GW_MCU\tools\wr\mpc5748_wr594\diab\5.9.4.2\PPCVLEE\libchar.a)'
dld: warning: Undefined symbol 'LzmaEncode' in file 'lib/lzma/LzmaLib.o'
dld: error: Undefined symbols found - no output written
scons: *** [out\app\test.elf] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

My question is not very clear but i want to know why i'm getting those linker erros and i'm looking for help from someone how had wworked with diab compiler since gcc does not give me this problem.

I don't know if the errors come from diabCompiler because in my laptop i got no problem
Can anybody help me please 
Thansk a looot

Comment: Maybe [THIS](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/undefined-reference-to-errors-when-i-compile-lzmautil-c-943284/) could help.

Comment: @LPs thanks it helped me, i was including some source files that i have not compiled in the MAKEFILE, However i get now some parse error from diab compiler , i will make a new post for that

Comment: If the above is an answer, then you should post as answer and mark this question answered.. :)

Comment: Whoa.. The ancient C compiler developed by DIAB data is still around? I've still got a DS90-10 workstation somewhere in the attic, I seem to recall the local terminal character set predating Latin-1 and using trigraphs for braces and brackets. </off-topic nostalgia>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try including all the source files used by the project and compile in the MAKEFILE, The error will probably disappear since you are using some functions that haven't been linked.

Comment: Did you just answer exactly the same as OPer selfanswered 5 days before?

Answer (score 2):

i was including some source files that i have not compiled in the MAKEFILE, The error disappeared after including all the needed files in the makefile.

Answer (score 0):

Check the read-only option for the generated file folders, also if you have added some content in the MAKEFILE then you need to check the read-write access for MAKEFILE folder. 
Some times the diab compiler has this problem with the folder access for newly generated files.
As the error is `.dld not found` it means a perticular file format is not supported.